# use const pointer or pointer as the key for `std::map`

Tags: c++, linux

```
#include <map>

class ClassOne
{
   //...
};

int main() {
    std::map< ClassOne *, int >             mapA;
    std::map< const ClassOne *, int >       mapB;
    std::map< ClassOne *const, int >        mapC;
    std::map< const ClassOne * const, int > mapD;

    return 0;
}
```

Question> I need to use address of `ClassOne` as the key for `std::map`. which one is the best choice?

Thank you

Comment: Do you *have* to use pointers as key? You are aware of the pitfalls of using pointers as key?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you actually want to do -- however, you seldom want to change keys, so `ClassOne * const`  if you're not intending to change the *pointer*; if you don't want to change the object that pointer points to, `const ClassOne * const`.